# How to pass arguments in remote ssh command

Tags: shell, ssh

I am trying to run the shell script in the remote host , with this i also want to pass some arguments. my local host shell scripts is below

```
pwd
echo $0
echo $1
echo $2
echo thanku everyone!!
```

To run this script am using the command

```
ssh user@server 'ksh' < ./code
```

I want to pass arguments with this command. please clarify me in this..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be possible to store the script on the remote server?

Comment: I am not storing. just running the shell script from local to remote host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass parameters because you are starting `ksh` and using `./code` as it's standard input.

But you can set an environment variable and then use it as command line, watch!

```
ichramm@wilderkrieger:~$ cat code
function run() {
    echo $1;
    echo $2;
}

run $COMMAND_LINE

ichramm@wilderkrieger:~$ ssh localhost 'COMMAND_LINE="hello world" ksh' < ./code
hello
world
```

Comment: No its not working.
    ssh user@host 'COMMAND_LINE="hello world" ksh' < ./thur1 
I used like this and my code is 
    function run(){
    echo $1;
    echo $2;
    }
    run $COMMAND_LINE

While running this code in host machine. its showing the following error

    syntax error : '(' unexpected.

please clarify me in this.. thanks..

Comment: -> please clarify me for the above comment.

Comment: That's because my `run()` is a bash function, while you need a [ksh function](http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/~johnb/comp/unix/ksh.html#functions) Just remove the parenthesis.